# Non-analytical correction for dielectric constant calculation in VASP

Tags: vasp, phonons, dielectric-constants

I am calculating the static (low-frequency) dielectric constant for a polar material in VASP.

Due to the LO-TO splitting, I need to apply a non-analytical correction. My question is how to do this correctly? It seems there is a way to use the `--nac` command in phonopy. However, it seems this is only possible e.g. in bandstructure calculations and I don't understand how to get the corrected dielectric tensor.

Could you explain step-by-step how this is done correctly? Thanks!